# Deleting a string between repeated delimiters in python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have to remove the strings that start with `"==="` and also end with `"==="` (for example I have to replace the string `"===Links==="` with null string) in python. But the problem here is it can start with three `"="` or four or any number of `'='`. I have tried to use the regex `re.sub('[=]*.*?[=]*', '', string)`. But when it is run on `"===Refs==="`, it is giving `"Refs"` as output instead of null string. Can you please suggest something for this?

Comment: Your description is a little confusing, but have you looked into [non-capturing groups?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-what-does-do)

Answer (score 2):

```
import re

string = '===Ref==='
pattern = r'^\=+.+\=+$'

string = re.sub(pattern, '', string)
```

Comment: @BhanuPrakashReddy glad to help, don't forget to accept the answer if this solved your problem

Answer (score 1):

Too late :-(

```
import re
str = '===Links=== are great, but ===Refs=== bla bla == blub ===blub'

pattern = re.compile('=+\w+=+')
replaced = re.sub(pattern, '', str)
print(replaced)
```

Comment: Honestly, this is the best one posted thus fa r because it's designed with scalability in mind.

Answer (score 0):

`.?` suggests that you are only accepting no or a single character between your `=`s. Try changing it to `.*` to match multiple characters between `=`s.

Perhaps you can use `str.startswith()` and `str.endswith()` to find out if the string starts/ends with `===`?